# How can I be able to move my GUI window in python

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to be able to move or drag the webcam window with the mouse anywhere on my desktop.
How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
def start_webcam():
    global webcam
    if webcam is None:
        webcam = tk.Toplevel()
        webcam.attributes("-topmost", True) 
        webcam.geometry('{}x{}+5+520'.format(WEBCAM_SIZE[0], WEBCAM_SIZE[1]))

        webcam.overrideredirect(1)    # I want this (because I don't want the windows title bar

        imgbox = tk.Label(webcam)
        imgbox.pack()
        imgbox.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.new('RGB',WEBCAM_SIZE,(0,0,0)))
        imgbox.config(image=imgbox.image)
        read_frame(imgbox)
```

Comment: Can I know what problem are you facing? in dragging it with the mouse.

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad it is stuck at the same place and don't moving with the mouse.